# Running IPv4 only application on IPv6 only network

Tags: 16.04, ipv6, ipv4, nat64, 464xlat

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 machine connected to an IPv6 only network. One application I want to run on this machine appears to not work properly with IPv6.

I know [464XLAT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6877) is supposed to make such applications work. The NAT64 part is operated by the ISP and is working as intended. However there is no CLAT on the Ubuntu machine, which is where I am stuck now.

Does Ubuntu support CLAT? And how do I enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tore Anderson has written a CLAT implementation for Linux. You can find it on [Github](https://github.com/toreanderson/clatd). It's just a Perl script that sets up the TAYGA daemon to do NAT46 (the IPv4-to-IPv6 translation) and configures routing in the Linux kernel, so that the ISP's NAT64 server can translate it back to IPv4.

In order to use `clatd` you need to install TAYGA and a few perl libraries:

```
apt-get install tayga libnet-ip-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libnet-dns-perl
```

Comment: Is there actually a kernel implementation? As far as I can tell it relies on `tayga` which runs in user mode. Not that running in user mode is necessarily a problem.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an Ubuntu package of the script. And when I install it directly from GitHub I don't get the dependencies installed. Do you happen to know which packages it depends on? I get this error on trying to run the script: `Can't locate Net/IP.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::IP module)`

Comment: Turns out I could use `apt-cache search Net::IP` to find the package name. After installing `libnet-ip-perl`, `libio-socket-inet6-perl`, and `libnet-dns-perl` the script no longer bails right at startup.